# Can I use 'bound' instead of 'possible' in this sentence?

Tags: word-choice

'There is bound for him to feel pain.'

I just wanted to avoid using possible and possibility too much and try to

use new words but properly.

so how do I use bound to mean 'high possibility'?

Can I say 'highly bound'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are various synonyms of the word possibility that can be used in this place. For instance, we can use plausibility or likelihood.

> There is a **plausibility** that he will feel pain.
>   There is a **likelihood** that he will feel pain.

The second sentence can be better put as:

> It is *highly likely* that he will feel pain.

If you really want to use the word **bound**, you can do so by slightly modifying the sentence:

> He is **bound** to feel pain.